# error al usar la funcion substring()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema con la sentencia `substing()` en SQL SERVER. Estoy tratando de extraer los 2 primeros dígitos de un campo de tipo `float`; el resultado que espero es 10 o 20, pero el resultado de la columna es 1., cuando debería ser 10 o 20

query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DataPerdidadSunat$ ADD PNPJ2 AS SUBSTRING(CAST(cRUC as nvarchar),1,2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está ocurriendo es que, al ser números *grandes*, la expresión

```
cast(cRUC as nvarchar)
```

Está devolviendo una cadena con el número en notación científica, algo como `1.01673e+010`.

Puedes comprobarlo con esta consulta:

```
select top 3 cRUC, CAST(cRUC as nvarchar) chrRUC
  from dbo.DataPerdidadSunat$
```

Que te va a devolver algo como

```
cRUC                   chrRUC
---------------------- ------------------------------
10167316668            1.01673e+010
10167316986            1.01673e+010
10167317176            1.01673e+010
```

El `substring('1.01673e+010', 1, 2)` es `'1.'`, como ya has comprobado.

Para evitar el problema, debes usar una expresión que devuelva el número convertido a cadena sin usar notación científica. Se me ocurren varias alternativas, una es primero forzar un número entero grande, pues los enteros nunca se escriben en notación científica.

```
select top 3 cRUC, CAST(cast(cRUC as bigint) as nvarchar) chrRUC
  from dbo.DataPerdidadSunat$
```

devuelve:

```
cRUC                   chrRUC
---------------------- ------------------------------
10167316668            10167316668
10167316986            10167316986
10167317176            10167317176
```

Si estás en una versión moderna de SQL Server y existe el riesgo de que un número sea tan grande que no pueda ser convertido a `bigint`, que soporta hasta 9223372036854775807, puedes valerte de [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
select top 3 cRUC, FORMAT(cRUC, '0') chrRUC
  from dbo.DataPerdidadSunat$
```

Devuelve también una salida como la anterior.

Una vez hayas elegido el método, ya puedes aplicar el cambio a tu tabla. Digamos, usando el primero:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DataPerdidadSunat$ 
  ADD PNPJ2 AS SUBSTRING(CAST(cast(cRUC as bigint) as nvarchar), 1, 2);
```

Comment: Y una buena práctica es siempre asignar longitud a varchar y nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo mencionó jachguate en su respuesta, el problema es que tienes números float muy grandes y al convertirlos a cadena se hace en notación científica.

Una alternativa para obtenerlo es usando la función `STR` combinada con `LTRIM` porque añade espacios al inicio. Dejo un ejemplo de lo que pasaría.

```
SELECT LEFT( LTRIM( STR( 13341876489734158486537679859616387643, 38)),2)
```

Uso la longitud 38 porque es el número más largo que permite usar SQL Server como constante entero.